# how to calculate the exact time taken to do autovacuum in postgres

Tags: postgresql

it say’s it took 179 hours but how it is possible to spent 179 hours from yesterday ?  Do i am missing anything ?

```
2019-04-22 07:40:34 CEST [30320]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "xxxx": index scans: 1
    pages: 0 removed, 28757389 remain, 5 skipped due to pins, 2159316 skipped frozen
    tuples: 28764881 removed, 189268339 remain, 5645787 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 481307580 hits, 107894548 misses, 52708943 dirtied
    avg read rate: 1.307 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.638 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 9467.79s/534895.45u sec elapsed 645049.35 sec

645049.35/60/60 =179.180 hours
```

Comment: It didn't start yesterday.  It ended yesterday.  It started 179 hours before that.

Comment: Thx I do remember i have seen the last_autovacuum column in pg_stat_user_tables to point to '2019-04-22 07:40:xx' i don't remember sec. so i thought it's same time when autovacuum  started.